# Drop an acid table failed in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveddl

I tried to drop an acid table in HIVE and it throws an error like this:

> Unable to get table: java.lang.Exception: ErrorCode: InternalError,
> Message:Not enable acid table

DDL：

```sql
create table `test`( `id` string,  `c1` string ) 
PARTITIONED BY (created_date date) CLUSTERED BY(id) INTO 6 BUCKETS 
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES (
    'orc.compress'='ZLIB', 
    'transactional'='true' );
```

So how can I drop this table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up hive Transaction manager properly before work with these kind of tables. Please run this command before your SQL to work with ACID tables.
`SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;`

SQL i used are below -

```
create table test( id string, c1 string ) PARTITIONED BY (created_date date) 
CLUSTERED BY(id) INTO 6 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ( 'orc.compress'='ZLIB', 'transactional'='true' );

SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
insert into test partition(created_date) select 'a','b',current_date();
select * from test;
```

[image: my result]

For permanent fix, you need to add below entries to hive-site.xml file.

```
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```